# 【CloudFront】Failed to load module script

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I deployed my web app using the amplify publish command, but the web page did not display. After checking the console, I found the following error message:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript 
module script but the server responded with a MIME 
type of "text/html". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts 
per HTML spec.
```

It seems that the MIME type needs to be corrected, but I do not know the specific procedure.

Could you tell me where and how to modify the Cloud Front console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cloudfront serving javascript modules as wrong MIME type( "Text/Plain")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925203/aws-cloudfront-serving-javascript-modules-as-wrong-mime-type-text-plain)

Comment: @KenWhite thank you! I'll try the answer to the post you provided.